# Take input values from modal and give it to hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii2-advanced-app

I'm working in yii2. In a form, I have a  bootstrap modal and modal further contain a form. Modal's form have dynamically input fields. I want all these inputs fields values to store into hidden input field to use in php code after whole form submits.

Currently i'm taking modal's form input in this way.

```
var values = [];
$.each($('#modal :input').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
      values[field.name] = field.value;
});
```

and then

```
 $('<input>').attr({
type: 'hidden',
value: values,
name: 'testvalue['+ testgrpid +']'
}).appendTo('form#reportform');
```

But this code is not working fine.

here 2 is testgrpid ...
currently i'm having this output in post in controller

```
 [testvalue] => Array
        (
            [2] =>[]
        )
```

but i want this type

```
 [testvalue] => Array
        (
            [2] =>[input name] [input value]
        )
```

please help me i'm stuck here.